# Deploying with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I trying to setup the Capistrano gem (following the *Agile Web Development with Rails* book - Fourth Edition). I setup git and all related directories\files on the remote machine (it works) and all "basic" things related to Capistrano. Now if I run from my local machine the following commands those work as expected:

```
cap deploy:setup
# ...

cap deploy:check
# ...
# You appear to have all necessary dependencies installed
```

At this time on the server machine in my project directory I have the following directories (created by Capistrano):

```
<my_project_dir>/releases
<my_project_dir>/shared
```

*Nothing more*.

**What I should do now?** For example, have I to upload all my application file from my local machine to the remote machine?

P.S.: I also setup my Apache2 server to point to the `<my_project_dir>/current/public` directory but Capistrano didn't create that folder.

---

**UPDATE** for *@Alex*

If I run the `cap deploy` command I get the following:

```
  * executing `deploy'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote root@<SERVER_IP_ADDRESS>:/git/<my_project_name>.com.git master"
    command finished in 3086ms
  * executing "if [ -d /srv/www/<my_project_name>.com/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /srv/www/<my_project_name>.com/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 36ccf7b6f63041ee8dcdf4ca0a7c0b10dbc8bad1 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q root@<SERVER_IP_ADDRESS>:/git/<my_project_name>.com.git /srv/www/<my_project_name>.com/shared/cached-copy && cd /srv/www/<my_project_name>.com/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 36ccf7b6f63041ee8dcdf4ca0a7c0b10dbc8bad1; fi"
    servers: ["<SERVER_IP_ADDRESS>"]
    [<SERVER_IP_ADDRESS>] executing command
 ** [<SERVER_IP_ADDRESS> :: err] Host key verification failed.
 ** [<SERVER_IP_ADDRESS> :: err] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
    command finished in 396ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /srv/www/<my_project_name>.com/releases/20110820175634; true"
    servers: ["<SERVER_IP_ADDRESS>"]
    [<SERVER_IP_ADDRESS>] executing command
    command finished in 353ms
failed: "sh -c 'if [ -d /srv/www/<my_project_name>.com/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /srv/www/<my_project_name>.com/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 36ccf7b6f63041ee8dcdf4ca0a7c0b10dbc8bad1 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q root@<SERVER_IP_ADDRESS>:/git/<my_project_name>.com.git /srv/www/<my_project_name>.com/shared/cached-copy && cd /srv/www/<my_project_name>.com/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 36ccf7b6f63041ee8dcdf4ca0a7c0b10dbc8bad1; fi'" on <SERVER_IP_ADDRESS>
```

*Note*: `failed: ...` on the last line. What is the problem?

Comment: Do you have SSH access to the machine using a public/private keypair?

Comment: @Alex - Yes (I think). A demonstration is that when I open my console on my local machine and I run the command '$ssh <my_username>@<my_hosting_service_server>.com' I do not have to enter the password and I am logged in to the server.

Comment: Is your git repo on the same server you're deploying to?

Comment: Are you using a deploy.rb file?

Comment: @Backo let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2695/discussion-between-alex-and-backo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your git repo is on the deployment server itself, Capistrano has same difficulties. Simply set the `deploy_via` variable to `:copy` in your `deploy.rb` to fix:

```
set deploy_via :copy
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> [<SERVER_IP_ADDRESS>] executing command
> ```
>
> ** [ :: err] Host key verification failed.
>   ** [ :: err] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

In my case, this was caused by having my git repo set up with an ssh URL.

I was able to solve this issue by logging into the host via ssh, then executing 'ssh ', then accepting the host key.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a couple of things:

- cap deploy:setup
  This will setup any dirs, symlinks, etc that capistrano needs
- cap deploy:check
  This will make sure everything is set up for cap
- cap deploy:cold
  This deploys and starts up all the configured daemons (eg mongrel, apache, whatever you're using)

Comment: 'cap deploy:cold' doesn't work. It generate the error that I add to the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform `cap deploy:cold` for the first time and then onwards use `cap deploy` or `cap deploy:migrations` to deploy the app.

These commands can either copy the code to the production server from local machine or even from the remote git repository.

Look at the configuration options here: http://help.github.com/deploy-with-capistrano/

The above commands will also create the symlink `<my_project_dir>/current` for you

The above error indicates that your server is not able to clone the git repository from github. Generate a SSK key pair in the server machine using app user and upload the public key to the github deploy keys..

Comment: Where I can find a web resource that explains how to "Generate a SSK key pair in the server machine using app user and upload the public key to the github deploy keys"? Then, what means "to the github deploy keys"?

Comment: BTW: I am deploying on a remote machine running Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Make sure that you are able to run the command successfully in the remote machine: git clone -q root@<SERVER_IP_ADDRESS>:/git/<my_project_name>.com.git /srv/www/<my_project_name>.com/shared/cached-copy

Comment: After I try to run that command, can I revert that process so to be sure?